# Why don't I have access to anything in my GCP Project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have created a google cloud project and enabled billing. I have used my email account (which is the project owner). I have created a new service user and made it a project owner, and also granted "Storage admin". I feel like I've tried everything, but I cannot build a docker image with cloud build.

```
$ gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/<project>/quickstart-image .
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) HTTPError 403: owner-445@....iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to project #########.
```

(I have replaced my actual project_id with `<project>`)

Why do I not have permissions even though I am the owner of the project, and even though I have explicitly granted the privileges?

---

Here is the output of my gcloud config list

```
~ $ gcloud config list
[compute]
region = us-east4
zone = us-east4-c
[core]
account = a**********0@gmail.com
disable_usage_reporting = False
project = *********

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

As can be seen in the screenshot below. The account that I am signed in as with gcloud is the project owner. My account `a**********0@gmail.com` should have god rights to everything, but it can hardly do anything. What is up?

[image]

Comment: What environment are you running your command within?  You may have to run gcloud auth login to login as a principal other than the service account.

Comment: `gcloud auth list` will show the accounts that you have setup. My guess is that you have assign permissions to one account but not another. `gcloud projects list` shows the projects IDs. `gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID` will show you the roles that you setup for each IAM member account.

Comment: I created the project with my gmail account. When I go to IAM. It shows my gmail account as the project owner. I have use `gcloud auth login` to log in as that user. I have confirmed that I am using the correct project and I have confirmed that I am signed in as the owner, but yet I still don't have access to do hardly anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the issue. When I set my project. I set the project name not the project id.

So instead of:

```
$ gcloud config set project <project_name>
```

I needed to do:

```
$ gcloud config set project <project_id>
```